# How to kill all the processes in OS X with a script

Tags: macos, process

I'm looking for a script that will kill all the processes on my Mac. To be more specific, the script should kill all the processes and shut down.

---

Well the point is that I want to kill all the procesess and **restart Mac OS X** but not shutting it down. I know that there exist commands like `sudo shutdown -r now` but it's not working on my Mac (that command is restarting it, but does not kill the processes after rebooting).

I can't use `sudo shutdown - h now` because I haven't got access to my Mac (only TeamViewer to connect to my Mac Mini). So I can't push the button on/off/restart.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: It often helps to ask for the *actual* problem you need to solve rather than your attempted solution. Why can't you just shut down the Mac without killing processes? The processes will quit anyway. What you're asking seems rather contrived. See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: You say that `sudo shutdown -r now` does not kill the processes AFTER rebooting. Well, no. If you kill all the processes, that'll include the init process which will once again halt your system. Rebooting will necessarily restart a number of processes.

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel J. pointed out, why can't you use

```
   sudo shutdown -h now
```

This will kill all processes on your computer and shut down the computer. Why do you have to "rewrite" a script that is already done by the `shutdown` command?

Answer (score 2):

Well you need a bash script that gets a list of all running processes and their PIDs and then uses a loop to kill each one of those PIDs like `kill 1002` inside the loop, once done you can call the shutdown process. The thing is that the shutdown process does that for you already.

Comment: No need to write a bash script. killall should work. Or heck, just `kill -9 -1`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a few specific processes you want to terminate, you could use `killall` and then use AppleScript to send `loginwindow` a `kAEShutDown` Apple event:

```
killall process1 process2
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to shut down'
```

If you want to shut down without being asked to save unsaved changes and so on, try using `sudo shutdown -h now`. It sends all processes a `TERM` signal followed by a `KILL` signal, which should be relatively safe even with graphical applications. If an application supports sudden termination, it is supposed to be safe to send it a `KILL` signal.

Normally when you shut down, Cocoa applications are terminated by calling the `applicationShouldTerminate:` delegate method, non-Cocoa applications and background processes are sent a `kAEQuitApplication` Apple event, and daemons are sent a `TERM` signal followed by a `KILL` signal. See [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW3-BAJJBJEG).

Edit: if you want to disable reopening applications after restarting, you can run `defaults -currentHost write com.apple.loginwindow TALAppsToRelaunchAtLogin -array '()'` before `sudo shutdown -r now`. The list of applications to reopen at login is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow.*.plist`.

Comment: Well the point is that I want to kill all the procesess and restart mac OS but not shuting him down. I know that exist command like sudo shutdown -r now but it s not working on my mac (restarting, but not kill the proceses). I can t use command sudo shutdown - h now because